# Can you score in Quidditch with a Bludger?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

I think I recall a Bludger counting as a point in either the movie or the Quiddich video game, but I can't recall for sure.

Is there any evidence for or against this assertion that a Bludger can score 10 points by going through a goal hoop?

Comment: I mean, if you hit a Quaffle with a Bludger and then the Quaffle goes through the goal hoop... I guess that would be valid?

Answer (score 8):

The Bludgers don't score points, they're purely a disruptive force.  The Quaffle scores 10 points per hoop and the Snitch scores 150 when it is caught.

> “This ball’s called the Quaffle,” said Wood. “The Chasers throw the Quaffle to each other and
>   try and get it through one of the hoops to score a goal. Ten points every time the Quaffle goes
>   through one of the hoops. Follow me?”
>
> [...]
>
> “See?” Wood panted, forcing the struggling Bludger back into the crate and strapping it down
>   safely. “The Bludgers rocket around, trying to knock players off their brooms. That’s why you
>   have two Beaters on each team — the Weasley twins are ours — it’s their job to protect their
>   side from the Bludgers and try and knock them toward the other team. So — think you’ve got all
>   that?”
>
> “Three Chasers try and score with the Quaffle; the Keeper guards the goal posts; the Beaters
>   keep the Bludgers away from their team,” Harry reeled off.
>
> [...]
>
> “This,” said Wood, “is the Golden Snitch, and it’s the most important ball of the lot. It’s very
>   hard to catch because it’s so fast and difficult to see. It’s the Seeker’s job to catch it. You’ve got
>   to weave in and out of the Chasers, Beaters, Bludgers, and Quaffle to get it before the other
>   team’s Seeker, because whichever Seeker catches the Snitch wins his team an extra hundred and
>   fifty points, so they nearly always win. That’s why Seekers get fouled so much.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sub>